# camera always rotate to 90 degrees

Tags: unity-game-engine

so i was writing some codes to make camera follows player, i already set camera rotation to 30 degrees, but when i test it, it always rotate to 90 degrees.
this is my code

```
public GameObject target;
    public float damping = 1;
    Vector3 offset;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        offset = target.transform.position - transform.position;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        float currentAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        float desiredAngle = target.transform.eulerAngles.y;
        float angle = Mathf.LerpAngle(currentAngle, desiredAngle, Time.deltaTime * damping);

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);
        transform.position = target.transform.position - (rotation * offset);
        transform.LookAt(target.transform);
    }
```

how to make camera rotates to 30 degrees instead of 90 degrees?

Comment: Could you show us a picture of how you have things set up so we can better understand what you mean when you say you want the camera's rotation to be 30 degrees instead of 90? And is the camera supposed to physically move along with the player or stay still and simply look at the player?

Comment: Sidenote: Your `Lerp` makes no sense .. usually you want to Interpolate on a constant value per frame like e.g. `0.5f` not making it dependent on `Time.deltaTime`, if your `damping` value is too small currently the camera will rotate almost nothing since the returned `angle` will almost stay `currentAngle`